# Android ViewPager Fragments - No Swipe and Preloading?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a pretty standard implementation of ViewPager using Fragments; however I'm wondering if it's possible to get rid of the preloading of tabs, and to only load a tab activity once user clicks on it?

Also, can we get rid of the swipe effect, just like in iOS?

Thank you

Comment: If you don't want the swipe effect, why are you using ViewPager at all?

Comment: what is an ideal way of implementing this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to only click on tabs, then don't use a `ViewPager`; put the views in a `FrameLayout`, make them all invisible and only set the view that is selected visible.  When the user clicks on a tab, make the current view invisible and selected view visible.  Much simpler than implementing a `PagerAdapter`.